# References on categorical TVS theory

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, topological-vector-spaces

A [survey by Castillo](https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-25-2/25J2Castillo.pdf) lists results on the category of Banach spaces and on Banach space constructions, such as:

- Existence of limits in Banach spaces or suitable subcategories
- Demonstrations of adjointness of functors, even where the natural isomorphisms are in a suitable Banach space type category
- Exactness of functors in Banach space type categories or weaker properties

I would like to know whether such results exist in a different TVS setting, and where to find them if they do.

Comment: What kind of results? Can you be specific for people who wouldn't go on to read the full survey?

Comment: @AmirSagiv Done.

Comment: In Schaefer's book, Topological Vector Spaces, sections II.5-II.8 deal with limits and colimits in locally convex spaces and facts such as every complete locally convex space being a directed limit of Banach spaces, and every bornological space being a directed colimit of normed spaces. The terminology is old-fashioned, however, and category theory is not used directly.

Comment: The monograph [_Derived functors in functional analysis_](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1977923) (Springer, 2003) by Jochen Wengenroth might be of use.